# Explanation for the following code in python

Tags: python, modulation, bpsk

`x=2 *(rand(N) >= 0.5) - 1`

Can someone please explain how the above expression corresponds to BPSK signal please?

Comment: Do you know what rand(N) generates?

Comment: Rule: *General programming questions are off-topic here, but can be asked on Stack Overflow.* There's nothing signal processing-wise in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Deviating from dsp a bit, randn(N) may be function you are looking for (numpy.random.randn(N)).
Coming to the question, yes randn will generate N gaussian distributed random values around 0. After that you are slicing (hard-decision) around 0.5 to get 0 or 1. These 0 or 1 will get converted to -1 or 1 (0 $\rightarrow$  -1 , 1 $\rightarrow$ 1) so you will have BPSK modulated symbols. 
(Since you chose 0.5 as the cutoff for deciding 0 or 1, this may result in more -1 symbols. You can chose 0 as the cutoff to get 1 or -1 with equal probability)